# Solving the algebraic equation $\frac{0.025}{10\sqrt{5}}=e^{\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{100}t}-e^{\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{100}t}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

While solving a system of differential equations of water flow problems, to find the time for the concentration to fall below $0.00005$ kg/L, I came across the following algebraic equation
$$\frac{0.025}{10\sqrt{5}}=e^{\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{100}t}-e^{\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{100}t}.$$
which I have to solve for the value of $t$. But I am facing difficulty in solving it.

I have tried solving this with Wolfram Alpha as well, but to no avail.

Comment: As an approximation: if the time $t$ that you're trying to find is large, then $e^{(-3-\sqrt{5})/100*t} \simeq  0$, and so you only have to solve a regular exponential equation.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28exp%281%2F100*%28-3%2Bsqrt%285%29%29*t%29-exp%281%2F100*%28-3-sqrt%285%29%29*t%29%3D1%2F2000*sqrt%285%29%2Ct%29) gives two roots,
$~0.025018769815917688569$ and $~889.6319702743134113$.

Comment: For the smaller root, you could write $bc=e^{-at}\sinh(bt)\approx e^{-at}bt$ so that $-ac=(-at)e^{(-at)}$ can be solved via the Lambert-W function. Or less exactly, use $bc\approx\frac{bt}{1+at}$ which leads to a linear equation.

Answer (score 0):

**not a full answer**
$$\frac{1}{400\sqrt{5}}=e^{\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{100}t}-e^{\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{100}t}=e^{-\frac{3}{100}t}e^{\frac{\sqrt5}{100}t}-e^{-\frac{3}{100}t}e^{-\frac{\sqrt5}{100}t}$$
Let $u=e^{-\frac{3}{100}t},v=e^{\frac{\sqrt5}{100}t}$
$$\frac{1}{400\sqrt 5}=uv-\frac{u}{v}\implies \frac{v}{400\sqrt5}=u(v^2-1)\implies \frac{v}{400\sqrt5(v^2-1)}=u$$
$$e^{-\frac{3}{100}t}=\frac{e^{\frac{\sqrt 5}{100}t}}{400\sqrt 5(e^{\frac{\sqrt 5}{50}t}-1)}$$
$$\frac{1}{400\sqrt 5} e^{\frac{3+\sqrt5}{100}t}=e^{\frac{\sqrt 5}{50}t}-1$$
this is the simplest form I was able to get it to.

Comment: You put "plus" instead of "minus",
it should be $\frac{1}{400\sqrt 5}=uv\mathbf{-}\frac{u}{v}$.

Answer (score 0):

As @razivo showed, you cannot expect a closed form for the equation
$$\frac{1}{400\sqrt 5} e^{\frac{3+\sqrt5}{100}t}=e^{\frac{\sqrt 5}{50}t}-1$$ Suppose that $t$ is large and neglect, for the time being, the $1$ in the rhs. This gives
$$e^{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{100}  t}\sim 400\sqrt 5\implies t_0 \sim \frac{100 \log \left(400 \sqrt{5}\right)}{3-\sqrt{5}}=889.632$$

Now, expand as a series around $t=t_0$ the function
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{400\sqrt 5} e^{\frac{3+\sqrt5}{100}t}-e^{\frac{\sqrt 5}{50}t}+1$$ to get
$$f(t)=f(t_0)+ f'(t_0)(t-t_0)+ O\left((t-t_0)^2 \right)\implies t_1=t_0-\frac {f(t_0)}{f'(t_0)}$$ which is the same as the first iteration of Newton method.  But, $f'(t_0) \sim 1.45 \times 10^{15}$ so $t1\simeq t_0$.

To give you and idea, the exact solution is $889.63197027431341130$ while $                                  t_0=889.63197027431341199$

Comment: Solution to OP is close to zero, about $0.025$.

Comment: @g.kov. There are two roots; the other one is $0.014304$

Comment: I mean, the equation you've solved is not the same as that in the question.

Comment: @g.kov. You are correct (sign error $-1$ instead of $+1$. Thanks & cheers.